# Interpreting script line

Tags: linux, grep, csh

```
set RMS = `grep RMS $runs/$run/log | head -$rms_it | tail -1 | awk '{printf "%.3f", $5}'`
```

I am trying to decipher one script.Firstly set defines RMS.Then I am confused,which pattern grep matches?

Comment: The variable `RMS` is set to the value of the command pipeline. The command pipeline looks for the string "RMS" in the file pointed to by the variable `$runs/$run/log` then further processes the found values. Note this doesn't look like bash.

Comment: @bishop Yes it is csh,you are wright!

Comment: you can execute parts of the pipeline by copy/paste onto your cmd-line. That way you can understand how each additional cmd changes the output stream. But `grep RMS /path/to/file` will probably produce a lot of output, so be prepared ;-). Good luck.

Comment: Google `csh why not`. The whole script could be written as a single awk command: set RMS = `awk -v rms_it="$rms_it" '/RMS/ && (++cnt==rms_it) {printf "%.3f", $5; exit}' $runs/$run/log`.

Comment: To truly rms_it you need to grow a beard and rewrite this script in LISP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly:

That `grep` finds lines which contains the string `RMS` in file `$runs/$run/log` (whatever that expands to)